# How to create JSP pages and Shared DB connection

Tags: java, database, jsp, jdbc, database-connection

I have a bunch of JSP pages.

I have a Java class that when initialized, gets a DB connection from the Connection Pool. I later use that connection in the JSP.

Is it possible to have one parent JSP page where I can define/get the connection and use it across all of my JSP pages and then close the connection when user hits logout?

Or please suggest what would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Get a connection from a pool, and close it as soon as your done with it (which returns it to the pool).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a datasource and publish it on the server using JNDI. Later in JSPs you can use this resource reference to perform queries to the database. You can also obtain a connection object from this datasource, but this connection should not be shared among users. You should return a connection to the pool after you finish with queries via closing a connection.

> The most efficient way to implement communication between the server and database is to set up a database connection pool. Creating a new connection for each client request can be very time-consuming, especially for applications that continuously receive a large number of requests. To remedy this, numerous connections are created and maintained in a connection pool. Any incoming requests that require access to the application's data layer use an already-created connection from the pool. Likewise, when a request is completed, the connection is not closed down, but returned to the pool.
>
> After preparing the data source and connection pool for the server, you then need to instruct the application to use the data source. This is typically done by creating an entry in the application's `web.xml` deployment descriptor. Finally, you need to ensure that the database driver (MySQL Connector/J JDBC Driver) is accessible to the server.

References: [Creating a Simple Web Application Using a MySQL Database](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html)

Comment: How about when the page is refreshed? the jsp page gets a new connection?